# List Comprehension Alternative code for For Loop

Tags: python

#### My code:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
k = 2

# where k is denoting the number of steps of rotations in an array.


for i in range(k):
    a = a[-1:] + a[:-1]
```

#### My expected Output:

```
['4', '5', '1', '2', '3']
```

How can I write this in List Comprehension?

#### I've tried this:

```
a = [a[-1:] + a[:-1] for i in range(k)]
```

Because I want to use List Comprehension Instead of For Loop.

I've heard that List comprehension is quicker than For Loop.

Comment: Please include in your question a description of what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Do you know what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry Just updated my question.

Comment: What does "nah doesn't work" mean? what does it do?

Comment: Try this: `a = a[-k:] + a[:-k]`

Comment: You can't do this with a list comprehension. A list comprehension can only fill in individual elements of the list, it can't concatenate lists like you do in the `for` loop.

Comment: a = a[-k:] + a[:-k]. This worked. Thanks for politely answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check out this code:** Make some tweaks in your code.
Here logic over which this code work is, take `last-kth items` in reverse order which is done by condition `i <= k` and add `last-element` using `a[-1]` and for other `n-k items`, `where; n: no of items in a object` add directly by help of `a[abs(k-i)]`, here
[image]

`3-i` takes value 0, -1, -2, -3 . . . .
but we want index as 0, 1, 2, 3 for `first n-k` items so use `abs(3-i)`

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
k = 2
a = [a[-i] if i <= k else a[abs(k+1-i)] for i in range(1, 6)]
print(a)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['5', '4', '1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: If the k = 3. My output is ``5 4 3 2 3`` instead It should be ``5 4 3 1 2``

Comment: k is denoting the number of steps of rotations.

Comment: @VenkataRamaDurgaprasadReddy Thanks alot for finding bug just make this change `abs(3-i)` to  `abs(k+1-i)`

Comment: I hope this will work and let me know If any isssue

Comment: It's working great. Thanks a lot